# Prove $P_n \to \Bbb Q X \Bbb Q X ...X \Bbb Q $, $f(a_n x^n+ a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+ a_1 x+a_0$)=$(a_n, a_{n-1},...+ a_1 +a_0)$ is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that $P_n =\{p(x)=a_n x^n+ a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+ a_1 x+a_0 |a_i \in \Bbb Q \}$  the set of the polynomials of degree n with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

I defined f: $P_n \to \Bbb Q^{n+1} $

by  $f(a_n x^n+ a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+ a_1 x+a_0$)=$(a_n, a_{n-1},...+ a_1 +a_0)$

I am trying to prove that this is a biyection and use the fact that $\Bbb Q^{n+1}$ is countable so $P_n$ is countable. The problem is that i could not prove that this is surjective

Comment: Start with an arbitrary element in $\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}$ and construct the corresponding polynomial $P$ which will be in $P_n$.

Comment: If you want polynomials of degree *exactly* $n$, not $\le n$, there is  little complication, since $a_n$ cannot be $0$  The fix is not too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function $f$ is injective but is not surjective. There is no inverse image of $(1,1,1,...)$ under $f$.

Since $f$ is injective, $|P_n|\leq |\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}|=\aleph_0$.

Since $\mathbb{Q}\subset P_n$, $\aleph_0=|\mathbb{Q}|\leq |P_n|$.

Hence $|P_n|=\aleph_0$z